# What is the character limit for an encrypted USB drive password in Disk Utility?

Tags: disk-utility, usb, encryption, filevault

Is there a character limit for an encryption password when formatting a USB drive as Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted) in Disk Utility? I was able to use a very long 65-character password but was wondering how much longer I can make it.

Answer (score 2):

FileVault 2, uses the User's login password as the encryption passphrase.<sup>1</sup>  macOS/OS X doesn't have a limit as to the length of a password<sup>2</sup>.

You can have a password without a limit, but practically speaking, it's not feasible to do so.

---

<sup>1</sup> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FileVault#Security

<sup>2</sup> https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22721/password-length-limits-in-history-of-operating-systems-and-popular-web-sites